# Make Payment iOS InApp Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am going to implement IAP (InApp Purchase) for buy some virtual goods using my application. I have go thru the documentation for implement this into the application. But i have a question, how the user can make their payment by using this way?

Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation covers this.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1) thoroughly. All the information you need is in there.

All monetary transactions are handled through a user's iTunes account.